# inner products and Euclidean distance between one hot vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't have much linear algebra background. I'm taking this online course on machine learning where the professor mentioned that the the inner product of two one hot vectors is zero (assuming the two one hot vectors are encoding different things). He also said that the Euclidean distance between a pair of (different) one hot vectors is also the same as the distance between any other pair of (different) one hot vectors.

I've looked around online a bit, but I'm sort of overwhelmed by the math used to describe the two concepts and I'm not sure I'm looking at the **right** math. Can somebody explain in simple terms why these things would be the case?

In case it's unclear, a one hot vector is a vector of all zeros except for a single entry where there is a one, so for example `[0 0 0 1 0]`.

Comment: The Euclidean distance shouldn't be zero if they're different, in fact the total opposite! The Euclidean distance should be zero if they're the same, while the inner product should be zero if they're different. In linear algebra, your 'one hot' vectors are often called 'standard basis' vectors.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood him. I've made a correction to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vector $x$, I'll write $x_i$ for the $i$th component, for instance if $x = (2,3,5)$, then $x_1 = 2$ and $x_3 = 5$. 
A quick review of Euclidean distance: the Euclidean distance between vectors $x=(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ and $y=(y_1, \dotsc, y_n)$ is given by 
$$d(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - y_i)^2}.$$
This is a generalisation of Pythagoras' theorem. Using the same notation, we can write the dot product
$$x \cdot y = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i.$$

Now, think about one-hot vectors. In that case, $x_i = 0$ for nearly all of the possible $i$s, except for one, which is $1$. Using the formulae above, can you see why the given statements should hold?

Answer (score 2):

Note that  $(0,1,0)^T(0,0,1)=0 \cdot 0 + 1\cdot 0 + 0\cdot 1=0$

One hot vectors are vectors with only exactly $1$ non-zero position which take value $1$ and the other value $0$. For two one hot vectors, the non-zero entry is being matched with a $0$ during dot product, hence the sum is $0$.

Comment: Do you mean 'dot product' instead of cross product?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that inner product is basically just matrix multiplication applied to vectors. I thought it was something more complex because of this page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html which is why I got overwhelmed :)

Comment: @B.Mehta yes, thank you.

Comment: The dot product is just a form of inner product. There are other generalization, however, I believe in your context, they are just using the standard dot product.

Answer (score 0):

Distance between two different vectors is always NONZERO, whether vectors lukewarm or icecold or frozen whatever. If zero, the concept of distance defined there must be something very much non-standard.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the professor. I've corrected the question.